# Accessing a json object nested in a json array with Python 3.x

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Given the json payload below, how do I get the value of 'hotspot' using Python 3.x?  The top level seems to be a a dict with one key value pair.  'Recs' is the key and the value is a Python list.  I have loaded the json payload into the Python class using `json.loads(payload)`.

**json payload:**

```
{
    'Recs': [{
        'eSrc': 'big-a1',
        'reqPs': {
            'srcIP': '11.111.11.111'
        },
        'a1': {
            'a1Ver': '1.0',
            'obj': {
                'eTag': '38f028e',
                'sz': 1217,
                'seq': '02391D2',
                'hotspot': 'web/acme/srv/dev/8dd'
            },
            'confId': 'acme-contains',
            'pipe': {
                'name': 'acme.dev',
                'oId': {
                    'pId': 'BDAD'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{` indicates a dict, `[` indicates a list so `hotspot` is at:

```
my_json['Recs'][0]['a1']['obj']['hotspot']
```

Comment: What is the [0] for between ['Recs'] and ['a1']?

Comment: `Recs` starts with `[` so it is a list, `[0]` selects first element of the list